# PDF under non injective transformations (LOTUS application)

Tags: probability-distributions, change-of-variable

I've been trying to better understand the proof of the LOTUS when the function $g$ between two scalar random variables $X$ and $Y=g(X)$ is not one-to-one.

I have followed two methods to show it (reported below). They use different writings to express the pdf $p_Y$ of $Y$ in terms of the pdf $p_X$ of $X$, which seem to be in disagreement.

Specifically, how can
$$p_Y(y)=\int p_X(x)\delta(y-g(x))dx$$
from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar), working for $g$ that are not necessarily one-to-one, and
$$p_Y(y)=p_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}(y)|$$
from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar)
be in agreement?

If I take $g$ one-to-one in the first equation I get
$$
p_Y(y)=... =\int p_X(x)\delta(g^{-1}(y)-x)dx = p_X(g^{-1}(y)),
$$
where the Jacobian is missing.

I guess I am making some mistakes somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Do you have any hints to help me out?

**Method 1 for $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is invertible.**

Following [Lotus Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Proof), we exploit $dx=dy/g'(g^{-1}(y)$ which cancels out the Jacobian for the switch $p_Y \to p_X$ like so:
$$
    \begin{array}{rl}
    E_Y[Y] &= \int y p_Y(y) dy 
    \\ &= \int y p_X(g^{-1}(y))\frac{d g^{-1}}{dx}(y) dy
    \\(p_Y\to p_X)\ &= \int y \frac{p_X(g^{-1}(y))}{g'(g^{-1}(y))} dy
    \\(dx=dy/g'(g^{-1}(y))\  &= \int y p_X(g^{-1}(y)) dy
    \\(y=g(x))\  &= \int g(x) p_X(x) dx = E_X[g(X)]
    \end{array}
$$

**Method 2 for $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ generic.**

Following [PDF Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar), here the relation $p_Y(y)=\int p_X(x)\delta(y-g(x))dx$ is used
$$
    \begin{array}{rl}
    E_Y[Y] &= \int y p_Y(y) dy 
    \\ &= \int y \{\int p_X(x)\delta(y-g(x))dx\} dy 
    \\ &= \int p_X(x) \{\int y \delta(y-g(x)) dy\} dx 
    \\ &= \int p_X(x) g(x) dx = E_X[g(X)] 
    \end{array}
$$